# How to extract files with extension from directories?

Tags: bash, shell, find

I am currently extracting pictures from a large multi-levels directory using the following bash command:

```
find . -name \*.jpg -exec cp {} /newdir_path_.. \;
```

However, all pictures are stored under 3 versions:

```
xxx-LD.jpg
xxx-SD.jpg
xxx.jpg
```

I just want to extract the `xxx.jpg` pictures, not the LD and SD... 
how should my command be modified to perform such extraction?

Comment: Would `echo *[!LS][!D].jpg` do it?  Its not strictly what you ask for, since it would reject any filename with a `D` before the `.jpg`, not just those with `L` or `S`.

Comment: What is the naming convention behind "xxx" ?

Comment: None just Numbers

Comment: If xxx is only `[0-9]` then that is much easier.

Comment: When LD or SD are present there is a dash before:  -LD and -SD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more tests:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -not -name '*-[LS]D.jpg' -exec cp {} /newdir_path_.. \;
```

`-not` is a GNU extension; you can use `! -name` instead. In some shells, `!` has to be escaped: `\! -name`.

Answer (score 0):

This may also work for you considering your filenames only contain digits before `.jpg`:

```
find . -iregex '.*/[0-9]*\.jpg$' -exec cp {} /newdir_path_.. \;
```